# Failed to open rowset. Details:42000:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

The error message that i get from crystal report it is in mandarin language.
[image]
  I get this message when running a Crystal report (using Crystal 9) that uses a stored procedure with 3 parameters - see SP below. Icreate a few temp table in it but when i test it on sql server it work. But when i run it in crystal report it prompt error. 
Any ideas welcome.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_rpt_pbos9003_test2]
(
    @moveType VARCHAR(3),
    @month VARCHAR(2),
    @year VARCHAR(4)
)
AS
BEGIN 

CREATE TABLE #Temporary
(
    scn VARCHAR(10),
    vsl_name VARCHAR(150),
    act_arr_dt_tm DATETIME,
    act_dept_dt_tm DATETIME,
    del_remarks VARCHAR(150),
);

INSERT INTO #Temporary

SELECT t1.scn, t1.vsl_name, t1.act_arr_dt_tm, t1.act_dept_dt_tm, t1.del_remarks
FROM vesvoy t1
ORDER BY t1.scn ASC


CREATE TABLE #TemporaryRelated
(   scn VARCHAR(10),
    Misc VARCHAR(20),
    Misc_amt DECIMAL(12,2),
    Cargo VARCHAR(20),
    Cargo_amt DECIMAL(12,2),
    Vessel VARCHAR(20),
    Vessel_amt DECIMAL(12,2),
    Credit VARCHAR(20),
    Credit_amt DECIMAL(12,2)
)

INSERT INTO #TemporaryRelated
SELECT t2.scn,
MAX(case when t1.inv_num like 'MI%' then t1.inv_num end) as Misc,
MAX(case when t1.inv_num like 'MI%' then t1.inv_amt end) as Misc_amt,
MAX(case when t1.inv_num like 'CI%' then t1.inv_num end) as Cargo,
MAX(case when t1.inv_num like 'CI%' then t1.inv_amt end) as Cargo_amt,
MAX(case when t1.inv_num like 'VI%' then t1.inv_num end) as Vessel,
MAX(case when t1.inv_num like 'VI%' then t1.inv_amt end) as Vessel_amt,
'' as Credit,
'0' as Credit_amt
FROM pbosinvoice t1
INNER JOIN pbosinvoiceitem t2 ON t1.id = t2.master_id
GROUP BY t2.scn


    CREATE TABLE #TempInvoiceDetails
(   
    payment_ind VARCHAR(1),
    void_flg SMALLINT,
    scn VARCHAR(10),
    move_type VARCHAR(3)
)

    INSERT INTO #TempInvoiceDetails
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.payment_ind,t1.void_flg,t2.scn,t3.move_type
    FROM pbosinvoice t1
    INNER JOIN pbosinvoiceitem t2 ON t2.master_id = t1.id
    INNER JOIN vosvesmovedtl t3 ON t3.scn = t2.scn
    WHERE t1.payment_ind='F'


SELECT t1.*,t2.*,t3.payment_ind,t3.void_flg,t3.move_type FROM #Temporary t1
INNER JOIN #TemporaryRelated t2 ON t1.scn = t2.scn
INNER JOIN #TempInvoiceDetails t3 ON t3.scn = t1.scn
WHERE ((t3.move_type = @moveType AND MONTH(t1.act_arr_dt_tm) = @month AND YEAR(t1.act_arr_dt_tm)= @year) OR
      (t3.move_type = @moveType AND MONTH(t1.act_dept_dt_tm) = @month AND YEAR(t1.act_dept_dt_tm)= @year))
RETURN

DROP TABLE #Temporary
DROP TABLE #TemporaryRelated
DROP TABLE #TempInvoiceDetails
END
```

Comment: your procedure selects data from other tables of your database. Any possibility your report is connected to wrong server or database? And is your post title the whole error text?

Comment: @jambonick i already check and it is connected to the same server and database because when i test it with only one parameter it works. The error is in chinese language so i don't really understand what is say, i only get the code for the error.

Comment: it works only with @moveType? can you show us how the WHERE clause of last SELECT is modified when you run the sp only with the first parameter? Also does the Chinese error text contains any English characters at all?

Comment: @jambonick                                                                                     SELECT t1.*,t2.*,t3.payment_ind,t3.void_flg,t3.move_type                   FROM  #Temporary t1
INNER JOIN #TemporaryRelated t2 ON t1.scn = t2.scn
INNER JOIN #TempInvoiceDetails t3 ON t3.scn = t1.scn
WHERE (t3.move_type = @moveType)                                                         I use this to call the sp                                                                                       **sp_rpt_pbos9003_test2 @moveType=ATA**

Comment: @jambonick i already snapshot the crystal report error in the question

Comment: Try to change month and year variables to int (in crystal reports number) and put the DROP TABLE commands before RETURN (or remove RETURN completely). Also display the exact SQL Command of the Crystal report if you can, I'd like to see how the sp is called with three parameters

Comment: @jambonick i called the sp with 3 parameter like this **sp_rpt_pbos9003_test2 @moveType=ATA, @month= 1, @year=2017**

Comment: Your parameters are compared to functions that return integer (MONTH and YEAR). Even if you declare your parameters as type of varchar, in sql server seems ok to insert integers values as inputs but I'm not sure about Crystal's conversion abilities. Try to use these to parameters as numbers (in report) and integer (in sql) and try again